# JQueryMobile not keeping default style for dynamically appended html

Tags: jquery-mobile

adding html to secondDIVContainer like below.  The html is being appended but it doesn't have the default formatting of jquerymobile.

```
$("#secondDIVContainer").append("<div id='2DIVHeader' style='text-align: center; margin:auto; height:auto;'>First aPTT Based Step</div><div id='2DIVBody'><div data-role='rangeslider'><label for='range-1a'>aPTT range for first step:</label><input type='range' name='range-1a' id='range-1a' min='0' max='0' value='0'><label for='range-1b'>aPTT range for first step:</label><input type='range' name='range-1b' id='range-1b' min='0' max='100'></div><label for='2Bolus'>Bolus Dose U/Kg:</label><input type='text' name='2Bolus' id='2Bolus' value=''><label for='2Rate'>Rate Change U/Kg/Hr:</label><input type='text' name='2Rate' id='2Rate' value=''><label for='2Test'>How Many Hrs before next blood test:</label><input type='text' name='2Test' id='2Test' value=''></div></div><div class='divDivider'>&nbsp;</div><div><a id='backImgLink2'><img src='img/back.png' id='backImg2' style='float: left;'></a><a id='nextImgLink2'><img src='img/next.png' id='nextImg2' style='float: right;'></a></div>").trigger("refresh");
```

I have tried trigger("create") which fails also.
I have tired calling the trigger function as a separate call and the fails too =(

Comment: Can you create a snippet where this problem can be reproduced and explain how it fails to meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to have the default formatting apply to a child div inside [div role="main"]. But when I changed the content of the [div role="main"] with an append command and triggered refresh...the formatting loaded just fine.